# Give file path in plugin

Tags: plugins, browser, npapi, firebreath, clutter

I have developed npapi plugin using firebreath. I want to access one image that is placed inside the computer. I am confused how to give the file path in plugin class or shall i need to place it in other specified folder?? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your main plugin object you can call [getFSPath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/class+FB+PluginCore+getFSPath)() to get the full path and filename of your plugin .dll.  You can use that to then find a relative path to a resource file you want to open.

In 1.7 or later (1.7 was released on Dec 17, 2012) you can `#include "BrowserPlugin.h"` and use `BrowserPlugin::getFSPath()` from anywhere. From there it's just a simple string manipulation, or if you want to be a little more complete / foolproof you could just use boost::filesystem

```
#include <BrowserPlugin.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

// ....

std::string getPluginDirPath() {
    path pluginPath(BrowserPlugin::getFSPath());
    return pluginPath.parent_path().string();
}
```

Comment: Hi!! getFSPath() will include the name of the .so i.e plugin library name in it. So how can i edit that to give it my file name??

Comment: Updated the answer with example code to do it with boost::filesystem; of course, you could also search for the last '/' and take a subtring up to that point. There are lots of ways to do it